# Your project was last opened with a different setup of utility

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to open my Unity project  in other version of Unity. How to open my Unity  project in other Unity version?

I get the following error:

> Your project was last opened with a differernt setup of utility

and

> The saved project(5.6.0f3) does not match the lunched
>   editor(5.5.3xf1Linux)

Below is an image of the complete error I get:

[image]

Comment: If you question is solved, don't forget to  [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The saved project(5.6.0f3) does not match the lunched
>   editor(5.5.3xf1Linux)

What's happening is that you saved a project with **5.6** version but you are now trying to open that project with **5.5** version. You cannot and should not attempt to do that. When you save a project, you should only open it with **the-same** software version or software version **above** the version you used to save the project.

The reason for what I said above is that the never version of Unity may have added new features to the saved data. They might have changed the structure of saved data too. There is no way old version of Unity can understand the changed data. This is why Unity implemented a feature to detect when you are opening a project with old version of Unity that was saved with a newer version. This prevents Unity from corrupting the project if successfully opened and modified.

The fix for your particular issue is to open the project with any Unity version above or equals to *5.6.0f*. That would be *Unity 5.6.0f*, *2017*, *2017.1* and *2017.2*....

Answer (score 0):

I had a new version and had this problem. However, I solved the problem as follows.

`Unity -> Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor` change the mode of version control from `Hidden Meta Files` to `Visible Meta Files`.